# How to add row number to my tree view?

Tags: python, treeview, odoo

I need to add row numbers to my tree views, so the user can have an idea about the number of records on the table. Is that possible?

I'm working on odoo8 with python 2.7

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: nice profile icon@boardriver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add Row number in tree view without creating new module. Please follow below steps and make changes as like below steps.

**Stpe-1 :** Open base.xml file resides in web module. (/web/static/src/xml/base.xml)

**Step-2 :** Search for **`<th t-if="options.selectable" width="1"  >`** in file.

**Stpe-3 :** Add line **`<th width="1">#</th>`** before the above searched line.

e.g.

```
<th width="1">#</th>
<th t-if="options.selectable" width="1"  >
```

**Stpe-4 :** Search for **`<t t-set="record" t-value="records.at(index)"/>`** in file and add line **`<t t-set="row_number" t-value="index+1"/>`** after that line.

**Step-5 :** Search for **`<th t-if="options.selectable" class="oe_list_record_selector" width="1">`** and add line **`<th width="1"><t t-esc="row_number" /> </th>`** before that line like,

```
<th width="1"><t t-esc="row_number" /> </th>    
<th t-if="options.selectable" class="oe_list_record_selector" width="1">
```

**Step-6 :** Search below line in file,

```
<t t-set="columns_count" t-value="visible_columns.length + (options.selectable ? 1 : 0) + (options.deletable ? 1 : 0)"/>
```

and replace it with below line,

```
<t t-set="columns_count" t-value="visible_columns.length + (options.selectable ? 1 : 0) + (options.deletable ? 1 : 0) + 1"/>
```

Now everything done. Just need to reload Odoo in your browser with Ctrl+F5, you will see the row number in tree view.

**Update :**
Download module from here [Row Number in List view](https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/11.0/rowno_in_tree/)